# Is it impossible to simultaneously use the unicode character left-to-right and the package inputenc with the argument utf8?

Tags: unicode

I have inserted a  'left-to-right mark' character (U+200E) just before and after $ in the following document and after compiling there is an error saying `ERROR: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:‎ not set up for use with LaTeX.` If I remove the line     `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` or just remove the argument `utf8`, the file is compiled without problem.

Is there a way to solve this this problem by keeping the line `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

‎$X$‎

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to set up TeX for supporting right-to-left writing; there are specialized packages for this, but probably switching to XeLaTeX and `bidi` is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always add a definition for character not yet set up. The main question is, what you expect it to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{200E}{Left-to-Right!!!}
\begin{document}

‎$X$‎

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much, the motivation of the question comes from the answer http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5840/2609. With you solution I just put\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{200E}{}.